# CoreData and NSTreeController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstreecontroller

At the moment I'm sticking around with the nstreecontroller that is backend with core data. My problem is that no rearrange get triggered if I edit a field or add a new row.

Structure:

- NSTreeController that is configured with prepare content ON and uses lazy fetching ON. The controller is bound to appDelegate.managedObjectContext and to appDelegate.mySortDescriptor (which is a function that returns an array with a nssortdescriptor inside).
- Outlineview that has his columns bound to treecontroller.arrangedObjects.name. The Outlineview is also in SourceList mode.
- An entity called "Item" that has a one-to-many relationship (children) to Item and a one-to-one relationship (parent) to Item. And of course there is a field called "name" that holds the displayvalue.
- two storages. One is only hold in memory and the default one. The temporary storage is used to set up the root entities (I don't want them to get stored because they're just "visual")

Until here everything is fine except for:

- On launch the sortdescriptor get read in but not executed (I've to call myself the rearrange function)
- no modification on the core data triggers the rearrange method

I already tried to solve the problem at me own with following results:

- Removing "Uses lazy fetch" will solve the problem o_O but who wants that?!
- Calling rearrange in outlineView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:byItem: (outlineview datasource) will solve the problem. But I do not really understand why this gets called (I'm using coredata, so it shouldn't get called?). On the other hand, calling rearrange to often messes up the sorting again (Ex. if you save a cell which hasn't changed his value)

That's the reason why I told myself that you've to face the fact that you're doing something wrong :)

What I actually want to have is the following:

- CoreData backend
- Outlineview is always sorted (the user cannot change it)
- Skipping the save of the root objects
- Less work is always welcome

thanks a lot and best regards, matthieu riolo

PS: Hints are appreciated too